# ReactJS props vs. state: end items detail

Tags: reactjs

Getting into ReactJS, I'm building a TodoList-of-TodoLists, a two level deep dynamic list of some items, identified by a numeric ID. Item has extended details that are retrieved from a 3rd-party service via their api.

React components structure is like so:

```
App {
  Level0Form,
  Level0List [
    Level0Item {
      Title: "ABC",
      Level1Form,
      Level1List [
        Level1Item {
          id: 123,             // given initially
          url: "abc",          // - updated after ajax call
          image: "image1.jpg", // - updated after ajax call
        }, ..
      ]
    }, ..
  ]
}
```

Initially app loads only Level0 *Titles* + Level1 *ids*. Then it makes async calls to ext. API to retrieve *url* and *image* (in this example) per each unique *id*. Same happens on interactive addition of new Level1 items.

What is the ReactJS way of passing these "decorative" details:

1. from root through chain of props, or
2. let every Level1 item request the details for itself, storing them in a state?

User does not change those details, which are only used for display purpose.

Answer (score 1):

***props*** :

- the way to pass data down to child components
- immutable
- you will get better performance passing data through props

***state***

- maintained by your top level component (view-controller).
- mutable
- do not use this to pass data to sub components

***TL;DR;*** - Use props to pass data to child components.

Comment: `props: .. immutable` – that causes my confusion: they **will** change as soon as ajax call returns data. Another is: `state: .. maintained by top level component` – consider them as one View, or a structure of Views, deepest nodes being also full-blown "Views", thus justifying *state* usage.

Comment: Your top level component should handle updating props. A recommended best practice for React is to have child components contain only markup, and the parent (Controller-View) handle events/data loading. Does that clarify the details a little ?

Comment: Yeah but it's free for a week. Try it out and then cancel if you don't want to pay. Most free trials work this way, and more importantly for the cost of 1 book a month you can have access to some of the smartest guys in the industry talking about their specialties.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'll have your components do the ajax call when the component mounts `componentDidMount` and when it returns you'll add the data from the ajax request, be it text or image or data, to the state `this.setState`.

If you choose to pass it down from the parent you'll need to receive the new props via `componentWillReceiveProps` which would then update the state.

`this.state` is key, because whenever you set it the component and all child components will re-render. And if you now have the new data from the ajax you'll need to re-render to show the changes.

But this is pretty basic react stuff. Go back and read the docs again. 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: "Ideally you'll have your components do the ajax call when the component mounts" --- a component that can perform ajax requests? It does not sound "ideal" in any universe.

Comment: Relying on *state* doubt is the initial rendering. There can be lots of end-nodes (Level1Items) initially. Each one will do its request and refresh. Its tempting to pack those in one batch ajax call to get all the missing info. Once received, do a single update of the whole interface, rather than one-by-one per node.